# React: How to change props values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my code, I replace these values

```
const [items, setItem] = useState<string[]>([]);
const [value, setValue] = useState('')
const [error, setValue]= useState('')
```

to this

type Props = {
items?: string[],
value?: string,
error?: string
}

and then change the following setItem, setValue, setValue which causes the following error

[image]

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

type Props = {
  items?: string[],
  value?: string,
  error?: string
}

export const TagActions = (props:Props) => {
    const { items, value, error } = props;

    // const [items, setItem] = useState<string[]>([]);
    // const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    // const [error, setError]= useState('')
    
    const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

    const handleDelete = (item:any) => {
        console.log("handleDelete", item)
        const result = items?.filter(i => i !== item)
        setItem(result)
      };
    
    const handleItemEdit = (item:any) =>{
        console.log("handleItemEdit", item)
        const result = items?.filter(i => i !== item)
        
        items = result    // setItem(result)
        value = item     // setValue(item)

        console.log("value", value)
        
    };

    const handleKeyDown = (evt:any) => {
        if (["Enter", "Tab", ","].includes(evt.key)) {
          evt.preventDefault();

          var test = value?.trim();
    
          if (test && isValid(test)) {
            items?.push(test)
            setValue("")
           
          }
        }
    };

    const isValid = (email:any)=> {
        let error = null;
    
        if (isInList(email)) {
          error = `${email} has already been added.`;
        }
    
        if (!isEmail(email)) {
          error = `${email} is not a valid email address.`;
        }
    
        if (error) {
            setError(error);
    
          return false;
        }
    
        return true;
    }

    const isInList = (email:any)=> {
        return items?.includes(email);
      }
    
    const isEmail = (email:any)=> {
        return /[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/.test(email);
    }

    const handleChange = (evt:any) => {
        setValue(evt.target.value)
        // setError("")
        
    };

    const handlePaste = (evt:any) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
    
        var paste = evt.clipboardData.getData("text");
        var emails = paste.match(/[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/g);
    
        if (emails) {
          var toBeAdded = emails.filter((email:any) => !isInList(email));
            
            setItem(toBeAdded)
        
        }
    };
    


    return (
        <>
          <div>
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: items?.map(item => (
              <Chip
                key={item}
                tabIndex={-1}
                label={item}
                onDelete={() => handleDelete(item)}
                onClick={() => handleItemEdit(item)}
              />
            )),
  
          }}
            ref={divRef}
            value={value}
            placeholder="Type or paste email addresses and press `Enter`..."
            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            onPaste={(e) => handlePaste(e)}
          />
          </div>
  
          {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
        </>
      );
}
```

I am a beginner in react typescript, so I don't know how to fix this, Please give me a solution to fix this problem

Comment: Because you declared it as a const. Means its a constant. So not supposed to be able to change it. Instead declare items with a 'let'

Comment: As error message stated that you can not re assign constant. You need to create new variable or use let or var.

Comment: Props should never be mutate. Instead you can emit an event to parent component with a callback props like "onChange" and then update value in parent.

Comment: The `items` property is declared as a `const` hence you can not change it or assign a new value to it, as is clearly mentioned in the error message. Also you must use state instead of directly modifying props, as react does not allow you to change/modify props.

Answer (score 0):

While changing `const` to `let` may fix immediate errors in the console, I doubt this will give you the behaviour that you desire.

The main issue here is that you are mutating the value of props, which in general you should never do. Props are used to pass stateful data down from a parent to a child component. If you wish to update the state of this data from the child component, you should pass an update function using props as well. Below gives an example of what I mean by this by implementing the delete item function (no typescript, but hopefully it gets the idea across):

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(["item1", "item2", "item3"])
  
  const deleteItem = (itemToDelete) => {
    //here we use the functional update form of setState which is good practise when the new state depends on the old state
    setItems((items) => items.filter((item) => item!==itemToDelete))
  }
  
  return <ChildComponent items={items}, onDeleteItem={deleteItem} />
}
```

```js
const ChildComponent = ({items, onDeleteItem}) => {

  //e.g. to delete item2 call
  onDeleteItem("item2")
}
```

This is one of the more confusing patterns in React, but it is very important to get your head around. Only the component where state is declared should actually be updating that state - as it is the only place where you have access to the `setState` function.